# Git show: Show blob in revision selected by text

Tags: git, git-show

I know that you can select a revision using the `:/<text>`-syntax [documented in gitrevisions(1)](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem), e.g.

```
git show :/"new change"
```

would show the (youngest reachable) commit with "new change" in the commit message.

I also often use [the feature](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem) to `git show` a blob in a specific revision, e.g.

```
git show myBranch:./coolFile.csv
```

to view the whole content of `coolFile.csv` (in a relative path to me) *in the state of revision* `myBranch`.

Now my question: Can I select a revision using the `:/<text>` syntax and then show a blob in that revision? I have tried

```
git show (:/"new change"):./coolFile.csv
git show :/"new change":./coolFile.csv
```

That threw the error

> fatal: ambiguous argument ':/new change:./coolFile.csv': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

so I tried

```
git show :/"new change" -- ./coolFile.csv
```

which printed nothing because that syntax only prints the changes of that revision in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command substitution (as in [Romain Valeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72558045/1256452)) or some other two-step process is usually the way to go.  Note, however, that the problem here is syntactic: `:/regex` has no way to *terminate* the regular expression and resume a revision specifier.  If we look at [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), we find that this `:/regex` or `:/<text>` syntax:

> ... names a commit whose commit message matches the specified regular expression. This name returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from **any ref, including HEAD**

(boldface mine).

Shortly *above* this description for `:/<text>` we find:

> `^{/<text>}, e.g. HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}`

described this way:

> ... is the same as the `:/fix nasty bug` syntax below except that it returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from the `<rev>` before `^`.

*This* syntax *does* have the equivalent of a "close parenthesis", namely the closing brace.  So if you're willing to search from `HEAD` or some other single ref exclusively, rather than from *every* ref, you can replace `:/foo` with `HEAD^{/foo}`, and this *can* be followed by `:./coolFile.csv`:

```
git show HEAD^{/new\ change}:./coolFile.csv
```

The fact that some revspec arguments cannot be appended-to was missed in some shell-script Git commands for some time, where people did things like:

```
set -e     # if/as appropriate
cmt=$(git rev-parse "$1"^{commit})
tree=$(git rev-parse "$1"^{tree})
... go on to use $cmt as the commit and $tree as the tree ...
```

when in fact we must do:

```
t=$(git rev-parse "$1")
cmt=$(git rev-parse $t^{commit})
tree=$(git rev-parse $t^{tree})
```

in case `$1` reads `:/fix nasty bug` for instance.

Answer (score 6):

You could have used [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) :

```
git show $(git rev-list -1 :/"new change"):coolFile.csv
```

(Here `git rev-list` just outputs the wanted revision hash)

---

***Note** (thanks to @phd): this is a bash mechanism, it won't work in windows cmd.*

Comment: Just a reminder: only works in Bash, not in cmd.

Comment: @phd Oh you're right, I should have mentioned it. Editing.

Comment: This method is very good and I appreciate the effort, however it is too complicated to use it as a shortcut (I wanted to use this method to not have to copy commit hashes, but writing this out everytime takes longer. Also aliasing would be less versatile). That is why I will accept @torek's answer although it is technically not as correct as yours.

Comment: @hoppla1232 I, too, upvoted torek's better answer. Glad to have been part of the discussion here, mate.